# Making a custom background image in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use a custom image background for my web application but no matter what code I try it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using the latest JQM version and I'm using this CSS tho it doesn't seem to work either.

CSS:

```
body {
background: url(Images/image.jpg) !important;
background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
}

.ui-page, .ui-content, .ui-btn {
background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: is the images folder inside the folder where the css file is? the url needs to be relative to the css file

Comment: I think you are unable to get the image. Check if the image url works

Comment: Oh wow i just needed to change the image directory , Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely JQM's styles are overriding your own. The easiest way to turn that off is by adding the attribute `data-role="none"` to the elements you are trying to change. If this breaks functionality, you could try overriding the css by using `!important` instead.